# Cannot install own package with `pip install .`

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have a package with a `setup.py` file importing external packages like `numpy` and `Cython` for building the package during installation. Here is how the top of my `setup.py` file looks like:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

import sys
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy as np

from setuptools import find_packages, setup, Extension
```

I would like to install my package in my current virtual environment (I am using `mamba`). To do so, I run

`pip install -e .`

However, I get this error:

```
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-u_xs09i6/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
```

### Things I verified

#### Verified cython is working

I know for a fact that `Cython` is installed and working, because I can import it from a python session:

```
❯ python
Python 3.9.15 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Nov 22 2022, 15:55:03)
[GCC 10.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Cython
>>>
```

And I also verified that both the session and `pip install` both are running the same python through printing the executable path (`sys.executable`).

#### Comment out `cython` import

I removed the `import Cython` statements in setup.py just to see what happens in `pip install -e .`, but now it cannot find the `numpy` package, which leads me to think something weird is happening where the environment is not discovered, even if it is running in it...

#### Install my package with a different method

When I install my package using `python setup.py --develop`, it works!

However I need the `pip install` command to work because the deployment system I am using runs `pip`.

Comment: ```❯ python --version
Python 3.9.15
❯ python3 --version
Python 3.9.15
❯ pip --version
pip 23.0.1```

Comment: `pip --version`? including its Python version…

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial and error, and starting from scratch, it turns out that the file `pyproject.toml` was the culprit....

According to the [docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/build-system/pyproject-toml/#build-time-dependencies), the file should list out build time dependencies, since the mere presence of the file [tells pip to use an isolated build environment](https://discuss.python.org/t/status-of-pyproject-toml-presence-triggers-different-pip-behavior/19156). When I added those dependencies to the file:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools ~= 67.0.0", "cython ~= 0.29.0", "numpy ~= 1.23.5"]
```

Things work now...